# Appium server not closing gracefully - Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2)

Tags: java, android, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I'm running an Appium server programmatically with the following code:

```
public class AppiumTests {

private AppiumDriverLocalService service;
private AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
private DesiredCapabilities cap;
public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

public void startServer() {

    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    builder.usingPort(4728);

    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
}

public void stopServer() {
    service.stop();
}


public void mobileTest() throws MalformedURLException{


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4728/wd/hub"), capabilities);

// My test cases are here

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    AppiumServerJava appiumServer = new AppiumServerJava();

        appiumServer.startServer();
        appiumServer.mobileTest();
        appiumServer.stopServer();

}
}
```

When i run this the Appium server starts as expected but i get an info warning  message as follows:

```
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@3ac42916
```

Full output:

```
Feb 28, 2018 11:10:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@58d25a40
Feb 28, 2018 11:10:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@3ac42916
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.2
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[Appium]   port: 4728
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4728
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.7.2","revision":null}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 76 ms - 72 
Feb 28, 2018 11:10:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@63d4e2ba
```

Any reason why this is happening? Certainly not sure why it's being displayed twice before the Appium server is even started.

Comment: It's possibly failing to call stop when running the previous test. There's [desired capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md) you can use to setup the tests.

Comment: There are no previous tests

Comment: Do you close your driver when the test(s) are complete?  It could be that the service is refusing to terminate because the driver is still open.